# Google cloud SQL export

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am trying to export CSV from Google cloud SQL to bucket. I want help to understand any bulk export mechanism, currently looks per instance we can export one CSV at one time.

Comment: A web search for "google cloud export database" returned official docs from google.com ... we'll help if you run into a wall, but please read the docs first.

Comment: It looks like you have already followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#csv) documentation on 'exporting data to a CSV file'. But your query on exporting 'multiple CSV files' is kind of a new 'feature request' for the GCP. I highly recommend you to open one through [this issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers).